# Using 'rvest' to extract links

Tags: r, web-scraping, yelp, rvest

I am trying to scrape data from Yelp. One step is to extract links from each restaurant. For example, I search restaurants in NYC and get some results. Then I want to extract the links of all the 10 restaurants Yelp recommends on page 1. Here is what I have tried:

```
library(rvest)     
page=read_html("http://www.yelp.com/search?find_loc=New+York,+NY,+USA")
page %>% html_nodes(".biz-name span") %>% html_attr('href')
```

But the code always returns 'NA'. Can anyone help me with that? Thanks!

Comment: Try using RSelenium. It works pretty well.

Comment: @Bharath, thanks! I know how to do it using RSelenium. I just want to see whether I can do it using only rvest package.

Comment: But even with the Selenium package, I am unable to grab the attribute, It returns NA again for me

Comment: You're in violation of clause B of their [Terms of Service](http://www.yelp.com/static?country=US&p=tos). They have an API. Why not use it?

Comment: @hrbrmstr, thanks. I will take a look at their API.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
library(rvest)     
page <- read_html("http://www.yelp.com/search?find_loc=New+York,+NY,+USA")
page %>% html_nodes(".biz-name") %>% html_attr('href')
```

Hope this would simplify your problem

Comment: Could you explain the "biz-name" section? I dont see that as a class.

Answer (score 12):

I also was able to clean the results from above which for me were quite noisy

`links <- page %>% html_nodes("a") %>% html_attr("href")`

with a simple regex string matching

`links <- links[which(regexpr('common-url-element', links) >= 1)]`.

Comment: Or, if you want to do this in the `tidyverse`, you can just add `%>% str_subset("your regex here")` to the end of that pipe.