# Using 'rvest' to extract links from main menu

Tags: r, rvest

I need to extract all the links from the menu of a page.

I've tried different css combinations but I cannot figure it out.

1° Approache:

```
library(rvest)     


linio_paths <- read_html("https://www.linio.com.pe") %>%
               html_nodes("#main-menu .subcategory-link") %>% 
               html_attr("href")

linio_paths #return character(0)
```

2° Approache:

```
library(rvest)     


linio_paths <- read_html("https://www.linio.com.pe") %>%
               html_nodes(".subcategory-link") %>% html_attr("href")

linio_paths #character(0)
```

I've visited this thread: [Using 'rvest' to extract links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35247033/using-rvest-to-extract-links)

It did help me with another site, but not with this one. Thank you.

Comment: Since they're loaded only when rolled over, it's easier to just scrape the site map (https://www.linio.com.pe/directorio), though check it's permitted by the Terms of Service.

Comment: This is the way I ended up doing things. Thank you!