# Trying to extract the links of r packages using rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I have been trying to use this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35247033/using-rvest-to-extract-links) and this [tutorial](https://stat4701.github.io/edav/2015/04/02/rvest_tutorial/) to get the table and links for the list of a[vailable rpackages in cran](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/available_packages_by_name.html)

### Getting the html table

I got that right doing this:

```
library(rvest)

page <- read_html("http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/available_packages_by_name.html") %>% html_node("table") %>% html_table(fill = TRUE, header = FALSE)
```

### trying to get the links

When I try to get the links is where I get in trouble, I tried using the selector gadget for the first column of the table (Packages links) and I got the node `td a`, so I tried this:

```
test2 <- read_html("http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/available_packages_by_name.html") %>% html_node("td a") %>%  html_attr("href")
```

But I only get the first link, then I thought I could get all the `href` from the tables and tried the following:

```
test3 <- read_html("http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/available_packages_by_name.html") %>% html_node("table") %>%  html_attr("href")
```

but got nothing, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, an "s" is missing: `html_nodes()` is used instead of `html_node`:

```
x <- 
  read_html(paste0(
    "http://cran.r-project.org/web/",
    "packages/available_packages_by_name.html")) 

html_nodes(x, "td a") %>% 
  sapply(html_attr, "href")
```