# Scraping Weblinks out of an Website using Rvest

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

im new to r and Webscraping. I'm currently scraping a realestate website (https://www.immobilienscout24.de/Suche/S-T/Wohnung-Miete/Rheinland-Pfalz/Koblenz?enteredFrom=one_step_search) but i don't manage to scrape the links of the specific offers.

When using the code below, i get every link attached to the Website, and im not quite sure how i can filter it in a way that it only scrapes the links of the 20 estate offers. Maybe you can help me.

Viewing the source code / inspecting the elements didn't help me so far...

```
url <- immo_webp %>%

  html_nodes("a") %>%

  html_attr("href")
```

Comment: I would suggest you to take a look at this.(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35247033/using-rvest-to-extract-links)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can target the `article` tags and then construct the urls from the `data-obid` attribute by concatenating with a base string

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)

base = 'https://www.immobilienscout24.de/expose/'

urls <- lapply(read_html("https://www.immobilienscout24.de/Suche/S-T/Wohnung-Miete/Rheinland-Pfalz/Koblenz?enteredFrom=one_step_search")%>%
       html_nodes('article')%>%
       html_attr('data-obid'), function (url){paste0(base, url)})
print(urls)
```